# How can I make UILable to respond to IBAction?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, customization, nib

I have customized UITableViewCell (Static Content Loaded from nib). This cell contains one UILable and I would like to change its value when user taps on it. (PickerView will be displayed and from that user can pick value for that lable).

So I have created following IBAction. But when I tried to connect it with that UIlable it does not allowed me to do so.

```
-(IBAction)selectlanguage:(UILabel *)sender
{
/*
 Code to display pickerview and select appropriate language
 */

self.languageLable.text=@"Spanish";

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.userTranslationLanuage = @"en|sp";
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Sumit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put an invisible button on the label that's connected to this IBAction. UILabel objects are not intended to respond directly to user touches.

Comment: Thanks. Decided to ahead with DateCell example of Apple. Just Pushing PickerView when user taps on that row.

Comment: That's best if that's the only action for a row. The extra buttons are only required if the row has more than one purpose, e.g. the row is for setting both language and country.